# how to insert multi records in yii session using ajaxSubmitButton

Tags: php, yii

I have been developing an application in Yii framework. At this point, I fall in an issue that is, I have an Order form where I select a registrant (all registrants come from database) from a dropdown, an item (all product items come from database) from dropdown and a input textbox where I type the quantity. There is a "ajaxSubmitButton" button to send all these values to the controller "actionCart" using Ajax. After receiving all values in the controller, I want to put all values in session variable. When I add another new item, the session values are being replaced what I want to hold all newly added items into the session variable. In this circumstance, what should I do. Please help me. I am giving my code snippets below:

in form:

```
<div class="form">
<?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'order-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-horizontal' , 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', ),

)); ?>

<div class="alert alert-info" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <p class="note">Fields with <strong><span class="required">*</span></strong> are required.</p>
</div>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'registration_id', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $data = CHtml::listData(Registration::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name');
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'registration_id',$data,array('class' => 'form-control chzn-select','prompt'=>'Select a Registrant'));
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'registration_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'item', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $data = CHtml::listData(Products::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name');
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'item',$data, array('class'=>'form-control chzn-select' , 'id'=>'item', 'prompt'=>'Select an Item')); ?>
        <?php
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'item'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'quantity', array('class' => 'control-label col-lg-4')); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <?php
        echo $form->textField($model,'quantity',array('class' => 'form-control','size'=>60,'maxlength'=>11));
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'quantity'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-8 pull-right">
    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Add to Cart',Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/order/cart'),
        array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'update'=>'#cartResult',
        ),
        array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-sm',));
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="cartResult" class="col-lg-12">
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionCart()
{
    if(isset($_POST["Order"])){
        $item = $_POST["Order"];
        $registration_id = $item["registration_id"];
        $productId = $item["item"];
        $quantity = $item["quantity"];
        $quantity = $item["quantity"]=='' ? 1 : $item["quantity"];

        $productInfo = Products::model()->findByPk(array('id'=>$productId));
        $totalPrice = $productInfo->price * $quantity;

        $session = Yii::app()->session;
        $session['cart'] = array("product_id" => "$productId" , "product_name" => "$productInfo->name", "quantity" => "$quantity","price" => "$productInfo->price");

    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that here you are not updating the session but always creating a new instance of and replacing new values in this $session['cart']

Comment: So, please help me the way how to update the session.

Comment: in your actionCart first check if $session['cart'] already contains a product id. if it exists then updates quantity  for that product else if this product id does not already exists add a new entry in session cart

Comment: Thanks Maz, I understand but I couldn't add a new entry in session cart using Yii. I use array_push() to add new item but it gives error. But it works if I use `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` instead of `$session = Yii::app()->session;$session['cart'] = array();`. Could you tell me how to add new item in the session variable.

Comment: You my using `Yii::app()->session['cart'] = array();` or `Yii::app()->session->set('cart', array());`